# Same SessionID used for multiple months for user in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

One of our databases tracks the date a certain page is viewed, along with the user ID and the session ID. We noticed that one user has had the same Session ID for months, even after new logins. Is this something normal or expected for ASP.NET, or is this a bug/vulnerability that should be addressed? This same Session ID persisted from October 10 2018 to Jan 24 2019.

The Session ID is pulled using `HttpContext.Session.SessionID` upon the action in the controller being hit.

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/122405/asp-net-web-forms-is-not-generating-a-new-session-id-if-a-user-logs-out-and-logs states this is a normal behavior and shows a way how to avoid it and what potential security issues arise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [ASP.NET Session State Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/ms178581(v=vs.100)), the default behavior is:

> By default, the SessionID value is stored in a non-expiring session
>   cookie in the browser. However, you can specify that session
>   identifiers should not be stored in a cookie by setting the cookieless
>   attribute to true in the sessionState section of the Web.config file.

I believe the same is true for ASP.NET MVC (as I cannot find any MVC specific documentation on session). So I would say, this is normal...